# What kind of light is this visibile in a mirror in a celeb portrait?

Tags: lighting, lights

[image]

I tried zooming in to the reflection but cannot tell at all what light she is using.. it gives a soft glow as I've seen from other celebrities Instagram. Please let me know if you have any idea. Thank you!

Comment: I always wanted to ask - why do people post screenshots of their phones instead of only the photo?

Comment: it looks like a LED panel https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?atclk=Head+Type_Soft+Lights&ci=12248&N=3988592074+3841992532

Comment: Given the blue cast, LED is a good bet.

Comment: @ths Because many apps don't make it easy to save photos, and it's easier to post the whole screenshot than to open in a editor and crop.

Comment: Note that all the walls are mirrored.

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree that the light is an LED panel. Judging from reflection cast and the years I've done lighting for shoots, I'd say it's a yellow gel. Warm LEDs aren't quite warm enough (I usually end up putting a weak yellow gel over them) to get a non-fluorescent view of a subject indoors. It was definitely the camera flash that cast the blue xenon-esque color on the model's clothes. That cast has nothing to do with the lighting on her.

Answer (score 1):

The light is an led panel with either warm leds or a yellow gel on top and it's not pointed directly at the model. The camera flash has also been triggered which gives off the blueish color on the model's clothes. The flash is also visible in the reflection.